# What is the best approach to upload 1000+ records to a server that also contains images for each record from an iOS/Android app?

Tags: android, ios, database, architecture, server

I have a app working offline. It is assumed that 1000+ records are created with images in each record during this period and whenever connectivity is established. What should be the approach to send all the 1000+ records to server that also handles any interruption between the network calls or API failure response.

I assume I have to send records in batches but how to handle the interruption and maintain consistency and prevent any kind of data loss.

Comment: I don't know this is a good suggestion or not, why don't you convert that records to a file(CSV) and upload to server and server handle the rest.

Comment: @jagapathi And what about the images?

Comment: then you have follow sync local to remote database

Comment: (1) It's your own server? Or you need a server as part of the solution? (2) what do you want to optimize on? upload as fast as possible? Or in the background with minimal cost for user? (battery, cpu, bandwidth..)

Comment: Use NSOperationQueue for uploading the records to server. it handles failure & success. Keep track of failures by setting its status. upload records in batches of 5/10 in background queue. this is iOS architecture. for android similar you can do with executor service

Comment: @auval (1) Yes (2) In Background efficiently with minimal cost to user.

Comment: Then it'd be best to extend Service and wait until your phone is connected to WiFi and plugged to a socket, and only then start uploading

Answer (score 4):

I guess the best way here is to send each record separetely (if they are not related to each other).

If you have media attachments, sending of each record will take 2 seconds in average, if you uploading via mobile internet with speed ~2 MB/s. If you will send the large batch of records via each request, you must have stable connection for a long period.

You can send each record as multipart request, where parts are record's body and media attachments.

Also you have no need to check for internet connection, or use receiver for catching changes of connection state. You can simply use this libraries for triggering sync requests:

1. [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)
2. [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)
3. [Evernote android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Firebase database API.
It has got nice offline/online/sync implementations.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

And it is possible to read/write the data using Admin SDK for your NodeJS server:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I have a MySQL Database at the server

Comment: I said you can use NodeJS to sync Firebase and your MySQL. Read the second url.

Comment: @Adnan , you even can reinvent the wheel

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: @Adnan I mean you can use ready-to-use database with nice sync android impelentation or create your custom approch and waste a lot of time.

Comment: @Adnan , this kind of db is most up-to-date.

Comment: The cost is also a concern to be taken in mind. I was looking for custom approach or any open-source tool

Comment: Refer this https://crisp.im/blog/why-you-should-never-use-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: @Adnan. And what do you waiting? There are always lots of advatanges and disadvantages in any project. This is a private opinion of a blogger. And what? This projects is developed by huge trending company. Lots of features are free of charge. Ultimately, I do not care how you will implement this feature and how you will waste your time. I've just wrote most useful database nowadays.

Comment: I appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Note. Firebase will remove all not synced local records when app is closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use divide and conquer approach means divide the task into small task and upload the data to the server.
1. take a boolean flag "isFinishData" starting with false.
2. starting upload the data on server from 0 to 100 records.
3. next record send from 100 to 200.
4. this process run until last record (1000) is not send .
5. in last record update set boolean variable true and exit from loop .

this logic would be work fine in IOS/android both.

Comment: In this example, 100 records are uploaded at once. How to determine how much records to upload in one request?

Answer (score 1):

Save your records in local Db and use ORMs for it. Use Retrofit which provide onSuccess and onFailure method for Webservice calling. To send data to server at regular interval you can use sync adapter.

Comment: I understand but will it be efficient for large data sets?

Answer (score 1):

- 1st I need to know how did you save image in local db ?
- You need to create a service to catch connection status. Each time when connection is established, you submit your record as Multipart kind. You can you Retrofit/Asynctask.
- Just submit 1 record per one Retrofit/Asynctask, it makes you ez to handle success/fail of each record.
- You can run a single or multi retrofit/asynctask to submit one or more record, it's up to you.
- If ur data has image, on server side, you have to handle process from ur server to 3rd server ( server to save image ).

Comment: I have image's path saved in my local db. The image is one way transfer i.e. from Mobile to server. 
What if I send record 1 by 1 and a record fails to sync what should be the approach?

Comment: if you sync single image, after each sync is done, sync next image. It makes sure that every sync process fail, the previous image is synchonized. And each time when sync is failed, just save a flag ( record's id ). And each time connection was establish again, start sync from saved id.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and it relates to Architecture, UI Experience, limitations, etc.

It seems to be a synchronization pattern where the user can interact with the data locally and offline but at some point, you'd need to synchronize the local data with server-side and vice-versa.

I believe the best place to start is with a background service (Android, not sure if there's a similar approach on iOS). Essentially, regardless of whether the Android app is running or not, the service must handle all the synchronization, interruption, and failure in the background.

If it's a local db, then you'd need to manage opening and closing the database appropriately and I'd suggest using a field to mark any sync'd records so if some records did fail, you can retry them at another point.
Also, you can convert the records to json array, then do a post request.
As for uploading images, definitely needs to be in batch if there's a lot of them but also making sure to keep track of which ones are uploaded and which ones aren't.

The one problem that you will run into if you're supporting synchronization from different devices and platforms, is you'll have conflicting data being synchronized against the backend. You'll need to handle this case otherwise, it could be very messy and most likely cause a lot of weird issues.

Hope this helps on a high level :)

Answer (score 1):

To take on simple approach ,have 1 flag in your data objects [NSManagedObject] classes as **sync**.While creating new object / modifying an existing object change **sync flag to false** .

Filter data objects with sync value as false.

```
let unsyncedFilter = NSPredicate(format: "sync = %@", @(false))
```

Now you will have an array of objects which you want to sync with server.If you are sending objects one by one in requests.
On success change ***sync flag to true*** else whenever your function gets executed again on app launch/reachability status update, it will filter out unsynced data again & start synch.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned this is a rather broad question. A lot depends on both the architecture of the server that will receive the data as well as the architecture of the app.

If you have any control over the implementation of your backend I would recommend implementing a storage solution that allows for pausing and resuming of transfers. Both Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3 offer a similar functionality.

The idea behind this approach is to be able to pick up the upload from where it stopped. In case of app crash or issues with internet connection you don't have to restart all from the beginning.
In your case I would still start separate uploads for each one of the records and store their upload progress.

Here you can find an example of how to use the pause / resume approach using the mobile SDK with Amazon https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/pause-and-resume-amazon-s3-transfers-using-the-aws-mobile-sdk-for-android/.

Editing adding reference to Amazon iOS SDK , http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

Comment: How about iOS? Does AWS provide mobile sdk for pause and resume?

Comment: @Adnan I just edited the answer adding a link to the iOS SDK

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to break the files into chunks of 100s and upload at intervals or when app is idle.